# How to use VLOOKUP result as COUNTIF criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, countif

I want to be able to determine how many times a person's particular ID (e.g. `#123`) has appeared in a separate column (e.g. `column C`) given a name (e.g. `Bob`).

I have:

> 1. Let column A consist of several names. (`Bob`)
> 2. Let column B consist of IDs relating to the person's name. (`#123`)
> 3. Let column C consist of those same IDs, however it may contain duplicates of the IDs (might have three `#123`s)

The IDs are side-by-side with each person's respective name.

How can I use the result of a `VLOOKUP` as the criteria (second argument) of the `COUNTIF` function?

If I use `VLOOKUP` separately it returns the correct value that I'm trying to count. `=VLOOKUP(Bob, column A:column B, 2, FALSE)` will return `#123`

If I use `COUNTIF` separately it returns the correct count value as well. `=COUNTIF(column C, #123`) will return `3`

I've tried `=COUNTIF(column C, VLOOKUP(Bob, column A:column B, 2, FALSE))` but it returns `0`.

I've tried referring the criteria for `COUNTIF` to a separate cell with the `VLOOKUP` formula but it still returns `0`.

So it seems like it stops working when I combine the two together. What might the problem be, and what might be an alternative?

Comment: hard to tell if you actually have bob or "bob"  , can you post your actual formulas please

Answer (score 6):

@Steve Martin has a valid point, but assuming `Bob` is text, your formula is correct though the syntax should be:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,VLOOKUP("Bob",A:B,2,0))
```

If this is what you are using and it is returning `0` rather than the correct result the most likely reason is that the `#123` in ColumnB is not the same as any `#123` in ColumnC. (In turn, the most likely reason for that is probably one or more trailing spaces - that do not show on inspection of cells in ColumnsB:C).

To check, just copy one of the `#123`s from ColumnC over the top of the first `#123` in ColumnB that is immediately to the right of `Bob`. Should you then see a result greater than `0` you are "on the right track" and may want to apply [TRIM](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) to remove surplus spaces.

In short, VLOOKUP attempts to match actual cell content rather than visible cell content and it recognises a difference between `#123` and `#123`  even though it does not display the two differently.

Comment: AHHHH I automatically assumed that there wouldn't be any trailing white space, so that was the issue. Thanks for the responses guys!

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,VLOOKUP(A1,A:B, 2, FALSE))
```

works perfectly. Always try to recalculate formulas by F9. Gl!